# NET8, Blazor and Microsoft Identity: error context instance before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm creating a new website with Blazor and the NET8 framework using the boilerplate from Visual Studio 2022 Preview. The source code of this test is on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/NET8BlazorIdentity).

As in my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77354692/upload-an-image-with-net8-and-blazor-in-the-user-profile-with-microsoft-identity), I have already changed the `ApplicationUser` adding a new properties such as

```
public string? FirstName { get; set; }
public string? LastName { get; set; }
```

Now, in the file *Index.razor* under *Components > Pages > Account > Manage*, I like to allow the users to change or add those values.

[image]

The important thing is that on the left side, in the _NavManu.razor, there is a place where I display the username or the `FirstName` like that

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Account/Manage">
                <span class="bi bi-person-fill" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                @(usermanager.GetUserAsync(context.User).Result.FirstName ?? 
                  context.User.Identity?.Name)
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

in the *NavMenu.razor* I added at the top of the page

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> usermanager
```

Now, when I try to save a new value for the *FirstName* for example, I invoke

```
if (Input.FirstName != _firstname)
{
    _user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
    await UserManager.UpdateAsync(_user);
}
```

Immediately, I get an error in the *NavMenu.razor*

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

The same code is working in the container of a NET7 Blazor application without issues.

[image]

Is there a way that I can fix it?

### Update

After the message from [H H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/h-h), I added in the *NavMenu.razor* this code

```
@code {
    private string? Username;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await 
            AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var fulldetails = await usermanager.GetUserAsync(user);
            Username = fulldetails.FirstName ?? user.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I can save an update as I can see here.

[image]

but if I click on any link, immediately I get this error

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem probably is `@(usermanager.GetUserAsync(context.User).Result.FirstName ...`

The (generated) BuildRenderTree method is not async and using `.Result` is asking for deadlocks.

When you `await` inside your `SaveAsync()` method a Render will happen (*) and that is where the conflict occurs.

The solution is to establish the userName in OnInitalizedAsync , not in the markup.

(*) I have to check that for SSR

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the code but now I get a different error.